# ISTQB Foundation Level Paper 3, no. 37

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, qa-developer, coverage, istqb

How many test cases are necessary to cover all the possible sequences of statements (paths) for the following program fragment?

```
if (condition 1)

    then statement 1

else statement 2

fi

if statement 2

    then statement 3

fi
```

The answer is supposed to be 3 but I don't know why? can someone draw a diagram or explain this? ISTQB Foundation Level Paper #3 no. 37.

Comment: Could you use brackets to represent any nesting ?

Answer (score 3):

It's three paths. If I express it via a more c# syntax you get this:

```
if (condition1)
{
     statement = statement1;
}
else 
{ 
     statement = statement2;
}
```

That gives us 2 paths:

```
condition1 == true -> statement1
condition1 == false -> statement2
```

Next, statement 2 is checked for true/false:

```
if (statement2)
{
    statement = statement3
}
```

So your 3 end points are:

```
condition1 true -> statement1 (value doesn't matter)
condition1 false -> statement2 true -> statement3
condition1 false -> statement2 false -> statement2
```

Comment: This is why having brackets is essential! Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think statement coverage is 2.

let's take

```
 condition1 = a>b
 condition2 = c>d
**test case1:**  a=3,b=1,c=5 and d=3
```

in this tets case statement 1 and statement 2 are covered

```
**testecase2:**   a-1,b=3,c=5 and d=3
```

in this case statement 2 and statement 3 are covered

i.e. with two test case we can cover all statements

so statement coverage is 2

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a small error in the content of the task asked by @Kristina ("statement 2" instead of "condition 2").
Assuming the following code below is OK:

```
if (Condition 1)
  then Statement 1
else Statement 2
fi
if (Condition 2)
  then Statement 3
fi
```

Flow chart:

[image: Flow chart to the task]

For me, the question is not entirely precise, because Statement Coverage is something different than Path Coverage.

To cover all the possible sequences for Statement Coverage we need 2 test cases:

- TC1: Condition 1 - TRUE, Condition 2 - TRUE
- TC2: Condition 1 - FALSE, Condition 2 - TRUE or FALSE

To cover all the possible sequences for Path Coverage we need 4 test cases:

- TC1: Condition 1 - T, Condition 2 - T (A-B-E-F)
- TC2: Condition 1 - T, Condition 2 - F (A-B-G)
- TC3: Condition 1 - F, Condition 2 - T (C-D-E-F)
- TC4: Condition 1 - F, Condition 2 - F (C-D-G)

So I am also confused about supposed correct answer (3).